# Is there a way to send OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader-NonQuery commands to execute on an API?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, odbc

I'm talking about a WinForm application that establishes a connection to a database via Odbc. But sometimes my VPN turns off but I have a server that is on the same network as the database.

Is there a way to override ExecuteReader function so that every OdbcCommand that wants to query is sent to a WebAPI and return the same object to the reader?

For example:

```
var cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT number, text FROM testing", Con);
var reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Then the reader obtains its value calling to https://example.com/api/tests/ and the code keeps working without VPN.

Please forget about security.

Comment: ( _waves_ hi Reddit!) I don't have enough time for a fully-fledged answer but you're probably going to want to write an extension method on `OdbcCommand` and handle the fallback logic yourself. You can't use an extension method to override the existing method but it should be a relatively simple refactor.